# Как получить индекс повторяющегося элемента в Python?

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм

Сравниваю поочередно левую и правую часть списка на равенство. И если они равны, то возвращаю число между ними, но вместо позиции 3, цифры 10, получаю позицию 1.

```
arr = [20,10,30,10,10,15,35]
# [1,100,50,-51,1,1]
def find_even_index(arr):
    n = 0

    while sum(arr[:1 + n]) <= sum(arr[2 + n:]):

        if sum(arr[:1 + n]) == sum(arr[2 + n:]):
            print(arr.index(arr[1+n]))
            return arr.index(arr[1+n])  # индекс позиции
        elif sum(arr[:1 + n]) > sum(arr[2 + n:]):
            print('Not allowed')
            return -1
        n += 1

find_even_index(arr)
```

Comment: У вас же уже есть индекс искомого числа в переменной `n`.

Comment: Что скрывается за формулировкой "поочередно левую и правую часть списка на равенство"? И что должно быть равно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы на каждой итерации заново вычисляете сумму всех элементов, кроме одного. То есть ваш алгоритм имеет квадратичную сложность.

А ведь есть решение за O(n):

```
def find_even_index(arr):

    left_sum = 0
    right_sum = sum(arr[1:])

    n = 0
    stop_n = len(arr)-1

    while n < stop_n:
        if left_sum == right_sum:
            return n
        left_sum += arr[n]
        n += 1
        right_sum -= arr[n]

    print('Not allowed')
    return -1


arr = [20,10,30,10,10,15,35]

print(find_even_index(arr))
```

Теперь, о том, почему не работает ваше решение.

Когда в списке несколько значений 10, и вы ищете значение 10, то компьютер в принципе не может знать, какую из этих нескольких десяток вам нужно получить. Поэтому он выдаёт ПЕРВОЕ подходящее значение.

И если разобраться, то вот это выражение:

```
arr.index(arr[1+n])
```

на самом деле совершенно излишне. В нём вы ищете позицию значения, которое находится в позиции n+1. Но если вы уже знаете, что оно находится в позиции n+1, то зачем вам искать, в какой позиции оно находится? Вы же и так знаете, что n+1.

Answer (score 0):

```
def index(arr, num):
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        if x == num:
            print(i)

index(arr, 10)
```

1
3
4